# word counting in python in file with spaces in name

Tags: python, string, file

Here is my code

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
word=input("Enter word to be searched:")
k = 0

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        for i in words:
            if(i==word):
                k=k+1
print("Occurrences of the word:")
print(k)
```

I am running it on windows if the file name is having spaces in it 
such as "some file xyz.txt"

then upon running the above code I am getting error

```
Enter file name: "some file xyz.txt"
Enter word to be searched:cs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/folder1/folder2/folder3/some file xyz.txt", line 5, in <module>
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"some file xyz.txt"'
>>>
```

How should I enter correct file name with spaces or the code itself is wrong?

Comment: just remove the quotes (") : `Enter file name: C:\Windows\System32\my file.txt`

Comment: @andrew_reece - Not a duplicate, the issue is the OP is including quotes in the input

Comment: "pogramming" != "programmming"

Comment: If you have a new question then you should raise it as a new question with what you've tried and researched, your edit completely changed the questions scope

Comment: I solved the original problem while I checked here.Sorry about the edits.

Comment: The title was uninformative for the previous problem you used it for and still is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enter the file name without quotes. Python treats your input as a whole string.